# Angular 8 - Get data in HTML Template (from array within array within another array)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Good day.

I have an API that produces this output:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
    dueDate: "2018-03-26T00:00:00"
    priority: {priorityId: 1, priorityName: "Critical", priorityColor: "red"}
    statuses: Array(1)
    0:
          status: {statusId: 1, statusName: "New", statusColor: "lightblue", ticketStatuses: Array(0)}
```

In my Angular HTML Template:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.priority.priorityName }}</td>
```

Produces: Critical (as one would expect)

But in the following statement that has an additional array:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.statuses.status.statusName }}</td>
```

Produce ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusName' of undefined

I expected a result "New"

Hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.statuses[0].status.statusName }}</td>`

since *statuses* is an array.